# narrow type using if condition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Code:

```
function useQuery(key?: string) {
  const searchMap = new URLSearchParams()
  if(!key) {
    return searchMap;
  }
  return searchMap.get(key)
}

const val1: string | null = useQuery('code') // type should be "string | null"
const val2: URLSearchParams = useQuery() // type should be "URLSearchParams"
```

For `var1`, TSC throws error:

> Type 'string | URLSearchParams | null' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.
> Type 'URLSearchParams' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

For `var2`, TSC throws error:

> Type 'string | URLSearchParams | null' is not assignable to type 'URLSearchParams'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'URLSearchParams'.(2322)

How can I make these two types correctly?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAjAZwKYEUwYE4CeAFANYYED8AXMmjHnBAOYCUyA3sMslEnbRgCGeKAAsAsoIAOyALzIIGAO7IAqgCUAMgGUhI0QAVhggLZoiLLsjggiAQjIE2nbtzwYYYPCkzCxkqQBuKwBfK3dPbwE-CWkAOiYPUnJLMOBeCH4AN0EAGwBGGjoGZmQAHwUwXNy5VEwcfGIAcl4AEwwmtgB6LuQYAikMWlEEKtbkACMhgCJixiZyyurp9L4YZBzcgCYaDR09MSM8UzRa9GxcQgtkHr6BobQRscmZvd0Yo5PpoA)

Comment: Sounds like you want function overloads. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: I posted a CW answer, but there has to be a good dupetarget for this... *Edit:* Yup, there is. [Here's the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwIojQJwJ4AUAlAFyICqASgDIDKaAhjhABYAKTDAtigNwBQoSLATJ0WXIQDWaPGRRQcMMAHNSiBUtWIAPojAgANoYFDo8JKkzZ8BGXgD88xcrVkqdRs3aceujS7aegbGiADe-IiIEAgKGl6sALIMAA6IALz6aADuFDT0TKwcONwoxJGIMMCIdrIZ6ZngACZowMpoTUThFVE4aFAgOEjohSzJKQJRAL4VfQND8aPjAHQq-bV4RPwz-DFgcQBuDIYAjM5aKv4hhhli1pIEAOQxLY9dAPTviFB4KWgaLDgRiaiAARv8AESaVxXIyGCG7WJQRBHQwAJnc+QSPhKfka4hshA+Xx+fwBQMMIPBiAhHgK3mKpQhQA) from my now-deleted answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Can I use conditional types to do this?

Comment: @slideshowp2 - I don't know. What use case do you have that conditional types seem more appropriate than function overloads or an overload type?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Overloads is fine. Just curious